# MongoShell query not working with Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Studio3T to generate my aggregation pipeline for 3 stages to join multiple collections. The staging output is displayed together with JSON data from that multiple data. But when i use the code provided in STudio3T to my Node Js Code, no data are displayed! i use Mongoose for ODM. What should i change in NodeJS before my MongoShell query are working?

here is the code

```
use Scheduling_system;
db.getCollection("timetables").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : { 
                "teacher" : ObjectId("5ea85945d9e58a0be4663aff")
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "from" : "classrooms", 
                "localField" : "classroom", 
                "foreignField" : "_id", 
                "as" : "join_classrom"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "from" : "subjects", 
                "localField" : "subject", 
                "foreignField" : "_id", 
                "as" : "join_subject"
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```

Comment: did my answer resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Mongoose then you should be able to import your schema like so and run the following:

```
import { YourSchema } from 'your-schema.schema';
```

and then...

```
YourSchema.aggregate(...)
```

Comment: Nope. i can't use the $match in node js

Comment: You should be able to, I often do.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html

Can you share your code?

Comment: here [link] (https://github.com/taqiuddinshokordey/Final-Year-Project-Web/blob/master/route/timetable_relief.js)